# Powershell command to change registry value data

Tags: java, powershell, registry

Is there a command for changing value data in the Windows registry?

I'm trying to change the `REG_MULTI_SZ` value `Security Packages` under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa`.

I will execute the command in my JAVA Project. With `getRuntime()`

Comment: Have a look at [Set-ItemProperty](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/set-itemproperty)

Comment: You might want to look at [this Scripting Guy column](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/update-or-add-registry-key-value-with-powershell/) or [this NetWrix blog entry](https://blog.netwrix.com/2018/09/11/how-to-get-edit-create-and-delete-registry-keys-with-powershell/).

Comment: You could probably use `Runtime.exec(reg.exe ...)` too

Comment: Your question is not clear. The subject asks about PowerShell, but then you mention a Java project.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest looking into `Set-ItemProperty`. This is the recommended way to modify the registry and filesystem through PowerShell.

[Link to documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/set-itemproperty?view=powershell-7.1)

Comment: Yep, that's what I commented some two hours ago already..